# Select element by dynamically changed attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

**Solved by @Grundy, solution at bottom of post**

I have a form with a radio option where the elements are selected programmatically and without the user directly clicking on the radio element.

```
var $elem = $("input[name=type][value^=foo_]"); // Select the element with name "type" where the value starts with "foo_" (assume only one value is ever found)
if ($elem.length > 0) // If element is found then toggle the checked value of the radio value
{
    $("input[name=type][checked=checked]").attr("checked", false); // Uncheck all existing checked items
    $elem.attr("checked", true); // Check the found element from before
}
```

This works, I can see the attributes change in Chrome's developer tools. The previous checked input is unchecked and the appropriate item becomes checked. This works every time specifically works multiple times (I'll explain why that's relevant later).

Next I hide all the unchecked radio buttons and show only the checked one.

```
$("input[name=type] + label").hide();
$("input[name=type]:checked + label").show();
```

This works the first time an input is selected. All the unchecked inputs will be hidden and the checked one will be unhidden. If the input is selected a second time (either immediately again or after other options have been selected in between) then all of the inputs are hidden including the checked one.

If I check the number of matched elements for `$("input[name=type]:checked + label")` it returns `1` for the first time and `0` for the second time meaning it won't be selected only after the second time. I feel like this is because the `checked` attribute has been changed dynamically at that point but that may not be the cause of the problem.

**EDIT - Here's a Fiddle**
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JoeyParis/YFdPa/) Clicking on the gray box will show you its normal behavior when changed by the user clicking on the values. Each value can be selected multiple times in any order but if you click the text at the bottom (they're poor looking buttons) it will change the form programmatically. It only works for the first time, it does not seem to care if it was selected by the user previously.

**Solution - Credit @Grundy**
Since I know the `$elem` object I found earlier is the object being changed I can reference it directly instead of trying to search for an element with the `checked` attribute. So I use this:

```
var $elem = $("input[name=type][value^=foo_]"); // Created before all the changes
$elem.next("label").show(); // Referenced after all the changes
```

Instead of using this:

```
$("input[name=type]:checked + label").show(); // Referenced after all the changes
```

Comment: I am not sure that you can change the state of a checkbox when the element is hidden.

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)..

Comment: @sdespont Chrome's developer tools show the attribute changing even when the elements are hidden. The problem seems to be selecting that element by the `checked` attribute.

Comment: @bios I'll work on a fiddle now.

Comment: @sdespont - I think you can change the state of the checkbox even if it is hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/f9eut/

Comment: @bios [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JoeyParis/YFdPa/) Clicking on the gray box will show you its normal behavior when changed by the user clicking on the values. Each value can be selected multiple times in any order but if you click the text at the bottom (they're poor looking buttons) it will change the form programmatically. It only works for the first time, it does not seem to care if it was selected by the user previously.

Comment: @JoeyParis Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/YFdPa/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use

```
$elem.next("label").show();
```

instead of

```
$("input[name=type]:checked + label").show();
```

because `$elem` is checked checkbox that you find

Comment: Still not sure why my way doesn't work but your way does and that solves my problem so thanks for the suggestion! Marked your answer as correct.